# Diffusion simulation

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to simulate a diffusion process and have the following code which simulates the diffusion equation:

```
dx = 0.1
dt = 0.1
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)
x = np.arange(0, 10, dx)
D = 1/20
k = 1

# We have an empty array
Cxt = np.tile(np.nan, (len(t), len(x)))
# Definition of concentration profile at t = 0.
Cxt[0] = np.sin(k*2*np.pi*x/10)+1
for j in range(len(t) - 1):
    # Second derivative to x: C_xx
    C_xx = (np.roll(Cxt[j], -1) + np.roll(Cxt[j], 1) - 2*Cxt[j]) / dx**2
    # Concentrationprofile in the next time step
    Cxt[j+1] = Cxt[j] + dt * D * C_xx

# Plot the concentration profiles in qt
%matplotlib qt
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
for i in range(len(t)):
    ti = t[i]
    Ci = Cxt[i]
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, Ci, label='t={}'.format(ti))
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('C(x)')
    plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 2])
    plt.title('t={0:.2f}'.format(ti))
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.01)
%matplotlib inline
```

I want to see how fast the maximum of the sine disappears. To do this I want to plot the amplitude (distance between maximum and average) as function of the time, but how do I do this?

How do I know at what time the amplitude is a factor e smaller than the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to fit a generic sine function `f(x)=A*sin(k*x+phi)+c` to the result data at each timestep and take its amplitude `A` as your result. This can be achieved as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
fit_function=lambda x,A,k,phi,c:A*np.sin(k*x+phi)+c
timestep=50
amplitude=curve_fit(fit_function,x,Cxt[timestep,:],p0=[1,k*2*np.pi/10,0,1])[0][0]
```

I picked the starting values `p0` to match your initialization. Of course you will want to wrap this in some way to answer whatever question you are asking, i.e. search for the value of `timestep`, where `amplitude` is below `1/e` or something.

Edit: Just taking the difference between maximum and mean for your data can be achieved as

```
Cxt.max(axis=1)-Cxt.mean(axis=1)
```

This will return a 1D-array indexed by the time.

Comment: can you upvote our question? also: is there a way of doing this, without using curve_fit?

Comment: What is wrong with curve_fit? I have added another option that matches your problem description better

Comment: I never used curve_fit before, so I'd like to avoid that

Comment: Well, you are here to learn ;). There might be alternative fitting functions available in scipy. But anyway it is a nice trick to have up one's sleeve.